# Permalinks not working with Vagrant

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to build up a little Wordpress development VM. When I select permalinks (postname) then the page from an article doesn't load. However, when I select the standard link (i.e page id) all is working good.
I've used the service PuPHPet to build the VM.

My settings can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/pYERZ7Xy)

I am using Wordpress 3.9.1 and Apache2
I've enabled mod_rewrite be executing:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And my .htaccess file from Wordpress is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /svisa/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /svisa/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

it has the following permissions and ownership:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant www-data   248 May 30 14:52 .htaccess
```

My virtualhost file for the site (`/var/www/svisa/`) can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/LayWVfJt).

from my host computer, I browse to the site via adress: `http://wpdev-vm/svisa/`
where `wpdev-vm` is the name of the vm.

Does anybody know what I am missing to make the permalinks work?

Comment: I assume the passwords in your pastebin are bogus ones. If they're not, you should probably change them *right now*.

Comment: @PatJ yes, they're not the actual passwords, and this is a local setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

In the default apache configuration, under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, where mine is called `15-default.conf`

This was declared under the document root:

```
   <Directory "/var/www">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

I had to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Thus you'll get the following:

```
   <Directory "/var/www">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

After that, the permalinks started working.

Comment: where exactly do I find the folders you specified? `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Comment: @Sumit, the directory sites-enabled is to be found on your virtual machine. The file 15-default.conf could be named differently at your machine. But it should have the "-default.conf" part in it

Answer (score 0):

There's sufficient info on the web about how to get .htaccess files working with Apache2. But specifically with *Vagrant*, you need to ensure the required settings are implemented in Apache on your *guest* machine. That might be obvious to everyone else, but I wasted an changing settings on my host and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.